# Transient voltage supression for high voltage Thyristor or Avalanche TVS

Tags: tvs, thyristor, transient-suppression

I am making a high voltage 240 VAC 60Hz voltage measurement front end and is in need of a transient suppression device. According the a table in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode).

[image]

Avalanche and Thyristors are the only remaining options to choose from. Are there any other factors that i should consider aside from the one in the picture?

I am leaning to use the avalanche type because it is something that i am familiar with in low voltage applications, so choosing parts is not that difficult i already even have a tentative part from [littlefuse](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/1-5SMC440CA/715119) and [bournes](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/bourns-inc/1-5SMC440CA/5320451). Thyristors on the other hand i am not familiar with the terms they are using.

Is it worth using a thyristor?

EDIT:

I have narrowed down a bit on the limits of what i want to protect, so far in my design process i have used 2000 V as my absolute maximum in term of component spacing, resistor selections, and isolation barrier. I tried to choose components beyond this where possible, but 2000V is where i draw the line. Also fits great for level 3 IEC/EN 61000-4-5 certification (im not going to certify this device)

Comment: You choose the surge suppressor based on the surge specification you are trying to meet and this needs to be revealed.

Comment: @Andyaka I do not plan on applying what im making on an actual certification so i really dont have a specification. This is just a "following good design practices" thing. But designing like i am applying for a certification sound good to me. I tried looking for a list of surge specifications but i could not find one, can you give me an example specification  so i can research its the others. I would like to meet maybe hopefully somewhere in the middle  not the lowest but not to high where super specialized parts are needed. After i found one ill come back and editt the question

Comment: I use EN61000-4-5 and, depending on what other surge protection devices are on the AC system I choose level 2 or 3 usually but you also need to define other things. It's not a 5 minute exercise.

Comment: If you don't have a spec to work to then you can't design protection because you don't know what the peak surge currents can be. EN61000-4-5 is for indirect lightning (fairly onerous).

Comment: @Andyaka turns out i already had the mindset of a EN61000-4-5 lvl 3. The weakest link i have  is only rated for 2000kV (component gap). So i guess i should be designing with that in mind. What other thing do i have to define good sir?

Comment: You need to determine what series resistance is appropriate for your set-up. This is the series resistance between the 2 kV source that generates the impulse and your cabling. If it's an AC port you will likely have to be rigorous and choose 2 ohm. This means a peak surge current of up to 1000 amps and you have to design your surge protector to limit the peak voltage that a surge of 1000 amps produces. This is where simulation is a big help; you should simulate what that surge current might generate at the end of the cable....

Comment: ... It's quite possible that an applied surge voltage of 2000 volts can nearly double to 4000 volts at the end of a cable that isn't grounded i.e. the surge current flows down one core to ground but another core (not connected to ground) can double to 4000 volts. I always simulate (and spend a lot of time on it getting it right) before actual surge testing.

Comment: @Andyaka 1000A, I think that would be too much for my measly circuit. How about if i let a device like [this](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/littelfuse-inc/SPD2-300-2P0-R/9951698) handle the heavy lifting and what will be on my circuit is local suppression would the TVS parts i linked be sufficient?

Comment: I think you would need to draw a schematic for this. I have my doubts and I don't want to try and guess what you propose. The device that actually does the heavy lifting is the device with the lowest breakdown voltage.